# Google form expense approval report

Tags: html, google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I am working at the expanse report  in Google form but in my workflow 
i got the email that send to the manager directly but when manager approve or reject the request i didn't get the email that have to send to the employee or requester directly but i need to run the function onReportOrApprovalSubmit() manually.
i think there is a problem maybe in trigger ...advice me please

```js
var APPROVALS_SPREADSHEET_ID = "";
var APPROVAL_FORM_URL = ;
var STATE_MANAGER_EMAIL = "MANAGER_EMAIL";
var STATE_APPROVED = "APPROVED";
var STATE_DENIED = "DENIED";
var COLUMN_STATE = 5;
var COLUMN_COMMENT = 7;

// Main tutorial function:
// For each row (expense report):
//   - if it's new, email the report to a manager for approval
//   - if it has recently been accepted or denied by a manager, email the results to the employee
//   - otherwise (expense reports that have already been fully processed or old expense reports 
//     that still have not been approved or rejected), do nothing
// Ideally, this function would be run every time the Approvals Spreadsheet or the Expense Report
// Spreadsheet are updated (via a Form submission) or regularly (once a day).
function onReportOrApprovalSubmit() {
  // This is the Expense Report Spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // Also open the Approvals Spreadsheet
  var approvalsSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(APPROVALS_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var approvalsSheet = approvalsSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  // Fetch all the data from the Expense Report Spreadsheet
  // getRowsData was reused from Reading Spreadsheet Data using JavaScript Objects tutorial
  var data = getRowsData(sheet);

  // Fetch all the data from the Approvals Spreadsheet
  var approvalsData = getRowsData(approvalsSheet);

  // For every expense report
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    row.rowNumber = i + 2;
    if (!row.state) {
      // This is a new Expense Report.
      // Email the manager to request his approval.
      sendReportToManager(row);
      // Update the state of the report to avoid email sending multiple emails
      // to managers about the same report.
      sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, COLUMN_STATE).setValue(row.state);
    } else if (row.state == STATE_MANAGER_EMAIL) {
      // This expense report has already been submitted to a manager for approval.
      // Check if the manager has accepted or rejected the report in the Approval Spreadsheet.
      for (var j = 0; j < approvalsData.length; ++j) {
        var approval = approvalsData[j];
        if (row.rowNumber != approval.expenseReportId) {
          continue;
        }
        // Email the employee to notify the Manager's decision about the  report.
        sendApprovalResults(row, approval);
        // Update the state of the report to APPROVED or DENIED
        sheet.getRange(row.rowNumber, COLUMN_STATE).setValue(row.state);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Sends an email to an employee to communicate the manager's decision on a given Expense Report.
function sendApprovalResults(row, approval) {
  var approvedOrRejected = (approval.approveExpenseReport == "Yes") ? "approved" : "rejected";
  var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
    + "<P>" + "PCS Manager" + " has " + approvedOrRejected + " your change report."
 + "<P>" + "Report Id: " + row.rowNumber
    + "<P>" + "Requester Name: " + row.name
    + "<P>" + "Change Request Type: " + row.changeRequestType
    + "<P>" + "Description: " + row.description
    + "<P>" + "Justifications: " + row.justifications
    + "<P>" + "Manager Approval Statues :" + (approval.approveExpenseReport || "")

    + "<P>Base Points: " + (approval.basePoints || "")
    + "<P>Cost($): " + (approval.cost || "")
    + "<P>Manager's comment: " + (approval.comments || "")
    + "</HTML></BODY>";
  MailApp.sendEmail(row.emailAddress, "Change Report Approval Results", "", {htmlBody: message});
  if (approval.approveExpenseReport == "Yes") {
    row.state = STATE_APPROVED;
  } else {
    row.state = STATE_DENIED;
  }
}

// Sends an email to a manager to request his approval of an employee expense report.
function sendReportToManager(row) {
  var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
    + "<P>" + row.emailAddress + " has requested your approval for a change report."
    + "<P>" + "Report Id: " + row.rowNumber
    + "<P>" + "Requester Name: " + row.name
    + "<P>" + "Change Request Type: " + row.changeRequestType
    + "<P>" + "Description: " + row.description
    + "<P>" + "Justifications: " + row.justifications

    + '<P>Please approve or reject the change report <A HREF="' + APPROVAL_FORM_URL + '">here</A>.'
    + "</HTML></BODY>";
  MailApp.sendEmail("p@gmail.com", "Change Report Approval Request", "", {htmlBody: message});
  row.state = STATE_MANAGER_EMAIL;
}





/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Code reused from Reading Spreadsheet Data using JavaScript Objects tutorial //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by its normalized column name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to all the cells except those in the first row
//       or all the cells below columnHeadersRowIndex (if defined).
//   - columnHeadersRowIndex: specifies the row number where the column names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the row immediately above range; 
// Returns an Array of objects.
function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
  var headersIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range ? range.getRowIndex() - 1 : 1;
  var dataRange = range || 
    sheet.getRange(headersIndex + 1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows() - headersIndex, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  var numColumns = dataRange.getEndColumn() - dataRange.getColumn() + 1;
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(headersIndex, dataRange.getColumn(), 1, numColumns);
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  return getObjects(dataRange.getValues(), normalizeHeaders(headers));
}

// For every row of data in data, generates an object that contains the data. Names of
// object fields are defined in keys.
// Arguments:
//   - data: JavaScript 2d array
//   - keys: Array of Strings that define the property names for the objects to create
function getObjects(data, keys) {
  var objects = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var object = {};
    var hasData = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
      var cellData = data[i][j];
      if (isCellEmpty(cellData)) {
        continue;
      }
      object[keys[j]] = cellData;
      hasData = true;
    }
    if (hasData) {
      objects.push(object);
    }
  }
  return objects;
}

// Returns an Array of normalized Strings. 
// Empty Strings are returned for all Strings that could not be successfully normalized.
// Arguments:
//   - headers: Array of Strings to normalize
function normalizeHeaders(headers) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
    keys.push(normalizeHeader(headers[i]));
  }
  return keys;
}

// Normalizes a string, by removing all alphanumeric characters and using mixed case
// to separate words. The output will always start with a lower case letter.
// This function is designed to produce JavaScript object property names.
// Arguments:
//   - header: string to normalize
// Examples:
//   "First Name" -> "firstName"
//   "Market Cap (millions) -> "marketCapMillions
//   "1 number at the beginning is ignored" -> "numberAtTheBeginningIsIgnored"
function normalizeHeader(header) {
  var key = "";
  var upperCase = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
    var letter = header[i];
    if (letter == " " && key.length > 0) {
      upperCase = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (!isAlnum(letter)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) {
      continue; // first character must be a letter
    }
    if (upperCase) {
      upperCase = false;
      key += letter.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      key += letter.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return key;
}

// Returns true if the cell where cellData was read from is empty.
// Arguments:
//   - cellData: string
function isCellEmpty(cellData) {
  return typeof(cellData) == "string" && cellData == "";
}

// Returns true if the character char is alphabetical, false otherwise.
function isAlnum(char) {
  return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
    char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' ||
    isDigit(char);
}

// Returns true if the character char is a digit, false otherwise.
function isDigit(char) {
  return char >= '0' && char <= '9';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your script goto `Resources -> Current Projects Triggers`

Add a new Trigger to -

**RUN** `onReportOrApprovalSubmit`  **Time-Driven** - **Day Timer** (8am-9am? whenever)

you could add a trigger to run `onChange`  but that would get busy with emails being sent.